# Replicating rows in a table by the columns

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012, excel-formula

I need to develop a report I create it in excel but it became so heavy that even my PC cannot open it.
Right now I decide to create it with SQL.
The excel input is something like this:

```
Service_order   PENDING_DAYS    SERVICE_TYPE    ASC code    INOUTWTY    Part_code1  Part_code2  Part_code3  Part_code4  Part_code5

    4182864919        18              CI         3440690        LP      GH82-11218A GH96-09406A GH81-13594A GH02-11552A GH02-11553A
    4182868153        18              CI         4285812        LP      GH97-17670B             
    4182929636        17              CI         4276987        LP      GH97-17260C GH02-10203A         
    4182953067        16              CI         3440690        LP      GH97-17940C             
    4182954688        16              CI         6195657        LP      GH82-10555A GH97-17852A GH81-13071A     
    4182955036        16              PS         6195657        LP      GH97-17940C
```

and the result using this codes

```
=HLOOKUP(Sheet3!A$1;Sheet3!$A$1:$F$10000;CEILING((ROW()-ROW(Sheet3!$A$1))/5+1;1);FALSE)"

=OFFSET(WholePart;TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($G$2))/COLUMNS(WholePart));MOD(ROW()-ROW($G$2);COLUMNS(WholePart));1;1)
```

* WholePart is partCode values.

are like this:
  [image]

What I want to do is to convert those formula or have an output just like this.
Appreciate it.

Comment: Based on your first EXCEL table I advice you load it as 2 separate tables `T1(Service_order, PENDING_DAYS, SERVICE_TYPE,  ASC_code,    INOUTWTY)`  and `T2(Service_order, Part_code)` and use JOIN to get the output needed.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are using.  Also, some explanation of what the formulas are doing would be helpful.

Comment: @Serg exactly which JOIN will help me have the result up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is prepare your data in EXCEL and load into normalized tables. Then you can get the result by joining the tables.

```
create table T1(
    Service_order bigint primary key,
    PENDING_DAYS int,
    SERVICE_TYPE varchar(10),
    ASC_code int,
    INOUTWTY varchar(10)
    );
create table T2(
    Service_order bigint,
    Part_code varchar(50)
    );

insert into T1(Service_order, PENDING_DAYS, SERVICE_TYPE, ASC_code, INOUTWTY)
values
    (4182864919 , 18,'CI',3440690,'LP'),
    (4182868153 , 18,'CI',4285812,'LP'),
    (4182929636 , 17,'CI',4276987,'LP'),
    (4182953067 , 16,'CI',3440690,'LP'),
    (4182954688 , 16,'CI',6195657,'LP'),
    (4182955036 , 16,'PS',6195657,'LP');
insert into T2(Service_order, Part_code)
values
    (4182864919,'GH82-11218A'),
    (4182864919,'GH96-09406A'),
    (4182864919,'GH81-13594A'),
    (4182864919,'GH02-11552A'),
    (4182864919,'GH02-11553A'),
    (4182868153,'GH97-17670B'),
    (4182929636,'GH97-17260C'), 
    (4182929636,'GH02-10203A'),
    (4182953067,'GH97-17940C'), 
    (4182954688,'GH82-10555A'),
    (4182954688,'GH97-17852A'), 
    (4182954688,'GH81-13071A'),
    (4182955036,'GH97-17940C')

select T1.*, T2.Part_code
from T1
join T2 on T1.Service_order = T2.Service_order
order by T1.Service_order, T2.Part_code;
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can load original EXCEL data (first table) and them normalize it in SQL.

```
-- create normalized tables
create table T1(
    Service_order bigint primary key,
    PENDING_DAYS int,
    SERVICE_TYPE varchar(10),
    ASC_code int,
    INOUTWTY varchar(10)
    );
create table T2(
    Service_order bigint,
    Part_code varchar(50)
    );

-- load data from excel.
create table excelData(
    Service_order bigint,
    PENDING_DAYS int,
    SERVICE_TYPE varchar(10),
    ASC_code int,
    INOUTWTY varchar(10),
    Part_code1 varchar(50),
    Part_code2 varchar(50),
    Part_code3 varchar(50),
    Part_code4 varchar(50),
    Part_code5 varchar(50)    
    );

-- Below i use sample data insert instead of load.    
insert into excelData(Service_order, PENDING_DAYS, SERVICE_TYPE, ASC_code, INOUTWTY
                   ,Part_code1, Part_code2, Part_code3, Part_code4, Part_code5)
values
    (4182864919 , 18,'CI',3440690,'LP','GH82-11218A','GH96-09406A','GH81-13594A','GH02-11552A','GH02-11553A'),
    (4182868153 , 18,'CI',4285812,'LP','GH97-17670B','','','',''),
    (4182929636 , 17,'CI',4276987,'LP','GH97-17260C','GH02-10203A','','',''),
    (4182953067 , 16,'CI',3440690,'LP','GH97-17940C','','','',''),
    (4182954688 , 16,'CI',6195657,'LP','GH82-10555A','GH97-17852A','GH81-13071A','',''),
    (4182955036 , 16,'PS',6195657,'LP','GH97-17940C','','','','');

-- store loaded data into normalized tables.

insert into T1(Service_order, PENDING_DAYS, SERVICE_TYPE, ASC_code, INOUTWTY)
select Service_order, PENDING_DAYS, SERVICE_TYPE, ASC_code, INOUTWTY
from excelData;

insert into T2(Service_order, Part_code)
select Service_order, Part_code
from excelData
cross apply (
    --unpivot
    select Part_code1 as Part_code where len(Part_code1) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code2 where len(Part_code2) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code3 where len(Part_code3) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code4 where len(Part_code4) > 0
    union all
    select Part_code5 where len(Part_code5) > 0
) unp;

-- check it
select * from T1;
select * from T2;
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't put the values each time in the query cause it takes a lot of time. And these values that you see is just the part of 10000 other values that I didn't select. Is it possible to do the same thing without separating the table?!

Comment: INSERTs are just  sample data to show join. You need to load data from EXCEL into DB only once.

Comment: the problem is that I have all 5 part code in one row, and I cant generate them in such way that each code show in one line, with the service order.

Comment: 5 part codes can be unpivoted in excel i believe using the =HLOOKUP / =OFFSET. It can be done by SQL query as well, see edit.